# iOS - App in Background vs Local Notifcations

Tags: ios

I'm building a project which is something like an Alarm Clock app.  I know there are inherit limitations here (as compared to the built-in Apple Clock app) but I'm trying to assess if these limitations will be a blocker.

In the end, I need to be able to schedule an alarm/notification at a certain time, and have it sound when the phone is locked.  Furthermore, I want to be able to interact with the app from the lock screen (including shake and volume gestures).

Does this require me having the app run in the background, and scheduling LocalNotifications?  If its in the background, and the LocalNotification fires on the lock screen, is it possible for the User to interact with the application?  i.e. With the app [SleepCycle](http://www.sleepcycle.com/), you can shake the phone from the lock screen to trigger a Snooze.  Is that sort of functionality possible only because the app is running in the background (in the case of that app, I know it's running in the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you need to be running in the background for interacting on the lock screen

Comment: If the app is running in the background, and a local notification occurs on the lock screen, will all gestures (aka volume button, shake, etc) be executed in the app's domain, or if the OS's defualt functionality take place?

Comment: sorry. this isn t a good answer and I can't answer the comment either

Comment: it is true what I wrote but I don't know more and it was really short - my bad